# error in creating directory using random function

Tags: php, css

I am trying to create a random directory for saving uploaded photos using the below code but its not working. Can anyone help.

```
//Photo upload script
if(isset($_FILES['profilepic']))
{

    if(((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")||(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png")||(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif")) && (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"]<2048576))
    {
        $chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM123456789";
        $rand_dir_name=substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,15);
        mkdir("./userdata/images/$rand_dir_name");
        //mkdir("\\userdata\\images\\".$rand_dir_name,077,true); //tried this but no luck

        if(file_exists("userdata/images/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]))
        {
            echo @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]."Already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["temp_name"],"userdata/images/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES[profilepic][name]);
            echo "Uploaded and Stored in userdata/images/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mkdir("./userdata/images/$rand_dir_name");`

This line should be either:

`mkdir("../userdata/images/$rand_dir_name"); //in this format if you are using one directory back to the relative path`

or

`mkdir("/userdata/images/$rand_dir_name"); //in this format if you are trying to create from projects root path`

or

`mkdir("userdata/images/$rand_dir_name"); //in this format if you are trying to create a directory from the relative path`

it cannot have single dot (.) followed by forward slash

Comment: Please check the file permissions of the directory that you are trying to use, does it allow directory creation or not